# Styling element like chrome tab without CSS3 transform?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8, css-shapes

I'm looking for a way to create a tab bar that looks like the one in google chrome without using CSS3 or image resources. I want it to work in IE8.
[image: Chrome tabs]

...

This is a [CSS3 example](http://codepen.io/minipai/pen/Etnhv) that I found on the Internet, but as you can see, it uses "transform", which is not available in IE8.

```
.tab-box {
  height:50px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  margin:0 10px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px  #fff inset;


 -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(30deg);
 -moz-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(30deg);

}
```

[image: Chrome style tabs]

Comment: Basically, if you are supporting IE8...background images. Otherwise, SVG.

Comment: The example uses `border-radius`, which is also doesn't work in IE8. You will not have any luck getting such a look without images. But ask yourself: do you care? So people with outdated browsers will get outdated rectangular tabs. Boo-frickin'-hoo. Maybe they should damn well upgrade instead of using an obsolete, outdated and extremely vulnerable browser?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Unfortunately, as much as I agree,  if the OP has specific guidelines he has to follow, for example he works for a company or is a freelance for a client, simply telling them to "upgrade" is not a proper response. It could also be that the site/software he is writing is made for a specific server software that won't run upgraded software.  (as of march 2016, 7.8% of users still use IE8 :C source: https://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx )

Comment: @AshleyWrench Yeah, I know... It's sad that something so easy as "not disabling Windows Update" is so difficult for so many companies... One can only hope the future brightens for us :D

Comment: The reason that I need IE8 compatibility is that I'm using a IWebBrowser2 control in an application that I'm currently writing. And that control always renders using IE. On XP you can't upgrade to IE9...

Answer (score 1):

For old IE<9 add the class `ie`,
for **non**-IE<9 browsers do your amazing stuff with gradient etc....

```css
html, body{height:100%; margin:0;font:16px/24px sans-serif;}
body{background:#abc;}
div{background:#fff;overflow:auto;}

/*TABS DEFAULT STYLES*/
/* here goes your awesomeness*/
.tabs{margin-bottom:0;padding:0;list-style:none;}
.tabs:after{content:"";display:table;clear:both;}

/*TABS IE*/
.tabs.ie li{
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  float:left;
  margin-right: -6px; /* (3) than adjust this value for the overlap */
}
.tabs.ie li a{
  background: #ddd;
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  margin: 0 12px; /* (2) adjust the value till the borders corner touch */
}
.tabs.ie li a:before,
.tabs.ie li a:after{
  content: "";
  position:absolute;
  top: 1px; width: 1px; /*(fictive 1px "roundness")*/
  border-bottom: 60px solid #ddd; /* (1) Edit px till border is not cut */
}
.tabs.ie li a:before{
  left: -21px; /* 20border + 1width */
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
}
.tabs.ie li a:after{
  right: -21px; /* 20border + 1width */
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  z-index:2;
}
/* ACTIVE TAB */
.tabs.ie li a.active{
  background:#fff;
}
.tabs.ie li a.active:after,
.tabs.ie li a.active:before{
  border-bottom-color:#fff;
  z-index:2;
}

.tabs.ie li:after{
  content: "";
  position:absolute;
  top: 1px; width: 2px;
  border-bottom: 60px solid #999;
  right: -10px;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs ie">
  <li><a>HOME</a></li>
  <li><a class="active">ABOUT</a></li>
  <li><a>PROJECTS</a></li>
  <li><a>CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>

<div><h1>ABOUT</h1></div>
```

Comment: Nice that seems to work. Is there a way to make the corners a bit more round?

Comment: @Forivin IE6,7,8? no.

Comment: probably you could manage to get a few extra px but  it would look pretty ugly.